# What is the correct way to parse extended hello messages in TLS protocol?

Tags: parsing, ssl, network-programming, wireshark

According to [RFC 5246](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5246) (which defines TLS protocol version 1.2)

Page 18:

> The record layer fragments information blocks into TLSPlaintext
> records carrying data in chunks of 2^14 bytes or less.  Client
> message boundaries are not preserved in the record layer (i.e.,
> multiple client messages of the same ContentType MAY be coalesced
> into a single TLSPlaintext record, or a single message MAY be
> fragmented across several records).

On page 40 it says:

> TLS allows extensions to follow the compression_methods field in an
> extensions block.  The presence of extensions can be detected by
> determining whether there are bytes following the compression_methods
> at the end of the ClientHello.  Note that this method of detecting
> optional data differs from the normal TLS method of having a
> variable-length field, but it is used for compatibility with TLS
> before extensions were defined.

What I understand from this passage is when I'm done parsing a `ClientHello` message, I should compare its size to the `TlsPlaintext.length` field of the encapsulating record layer message to see if there are any extra bytes at the end of record layer messsage, and if there are, interpret them as `Extension` structures.

This actually works correctly for some of TLS traffic samples that I test my app with, but fails for some other (i.e. it fails to detect messages that wireshark can). When I look at the problematic packet using wireshark, It looks like several handshake messages combined into a single handshake message. These are a `ServerHello` (which looks exactly like `ClientHello`) with extensions present, a `Certificate` and `ServerHelloDone` message.

Detecting Hello extensions is easy when Hello message is encapsulated inside a single handshake message, but I can't understand how is it possible to detect presence and boundaries of extension part after a hello message when there exist other handshake messages in the same message after them.

Any help or suggestion on how to parse these packets would be appreciated.

Comment: Don't use code formatting for text that isn't code, and do use quote formatting for text that is quoted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Every TLS message belonging to (hanshake protocol, Change Cipher Spec Protocol, Alert Protocol, other protocol) is sent within (or above) the Record Layer Protocol. Take a look at this: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc767139.aspx

Record Layer protocol will provide:

- Content type (1 Octet)
- Version (2 Octets)
- Length (2 Octets)

Every TLS message will begin with these fields, even when you see many SSL messages in the payload of the same TCP segment. You can parse those messages as separate TLS messages.

The Length in the SSL Record Protocol will give you the total length of the upper-layer protocol message. If it is a Hello message as part of Handshake protocol, it will include the extensions. This field will also let you determine the boundaries or many TLS messages coming together.

In the case of the Hello message, after compression methods field, you have 2 Octets indicating extensions length. The extensions are included in the Length field of the SSL Record Protocol containing the Hello message. They are also included in the Length of the same Hello message.

After the SSL Record Layer, every message of a different protocol is parsed in its own way:

- Change Cipher Spec Protocol: always 1 Octet
- Handshake protocol: TLV (Type, Length, Value)
- Alert Protocol: 2 Octets (Level, Alert)
- HTTP or other ...

So, when you have many TLS messages coming together in the same TCP segment, you always:

```
Offset = 0
While more data (based on TCP payload length):
    Read first 5 octets at Offset
        Obtain Length field (Assign to MessageLength, Offset += 5)
            Process first TLS message from Offset, with length MessageLength
            Offset += MessageLength
```

I hope I'm addressing your question correctly ...

Comment: Thanks, I didn't realize presence of extensions have also been reflected in length of handshake message in addition to record layer message.